# How to convert milliseconds to formated DateTime in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, datetime, formatting

After de-serializing JSON from server I have got date-time in milliseconds: `$scope.JDT = "1492499995056";`. I can display scope variable 'JDT' on my view using filter:

{{JDT | date:"dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss a"}}

... however, I don't really need it. I want to use this filter inside my scope instead, to populate another scope variable by such a formatted data but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the filter like this in the controller

`$scope.sample = $filter('date')($scope.JDT,"dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss a");`

demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$filter){
$scope.JDT = "1492499995056"

$scope.sample = $filter('date')($scope.JDT,"dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
console.log($scope.sample)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject [**`$filter`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter) in your controller and, have something like this:

```
$scope.someVariable = $filter('date')($scope.JDT, 'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss a')
```

Comment: ... thanks, I have tried it before and didn't work, I have spent one hour analyzing it but without any result and now when I saw your example I have realized that I haven't injected $filter into controller :)  ...